# How to select converted field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, date-formatting

I have to get those user records whose birthday is uqual to given date. Since the date format of `birthday` is `"Y-d-m"` in my database, first I need to convert it to `"d-m"` format. After that select this field. I use the query something like:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%d-%m') AS birthday_date
FROM users
WHERE birthday_date = '03-06'
```

but it returns unknown column error:

```
Unknown column 'birthday_date' in 'where clause'
```

So how can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use having :)

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%d-%m') AS birthday_date
FROM users
HAVING DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%d-%m') = '03-06'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%d-%m') AS birthday_date
    FROM users
) a
WHERE a.birthday_date = '03-06'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(birthday, '%d-%m') AS birthday_date
  FROM users
)
WHERE birthday_date = '03-06'
```

You cannot use alias in where clause